# Class Not Found: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, jsp

I am not sure why I am getting a class not found. I have included the mysql jar file. 
I am using JSP to call classes I have written, which `BookStoreLogic.java` connects to the database.

**Error:**  `HTTP Status 500 - javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

**Screenshot (Project Explorer):** 
 [image]

Thank you for the help I appreciate it.

Comment: Show us the servlet code

Comment: Try restarting your IDE, that sometimes help. Can you show us your full classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a lib folder inside WEB-INF folder, then add your database driver there. Every jar inside lib folder will be automatically deployed together with your web application.

Your folder tree should look like this:

```
+ WEB-INF
  + lib
    - mysql-connector-jar-5.1.28-bin.jar
```

Comment: Ahhh, Thanks I'll go ahead and try that!

Comment: Thanks that fixed my problem, I will mark as solution in 4 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you already added connector jar to your project build path you can add it to our `WEB-INF/lib` via

`YourProject` -> `properties` -> `Deployment Assembly` -> `add` -> `Java Build Path Entries` -> select `mysql-connector ...jar` -> `finish`.

Answer (score 0):

Upon downloading the mysql jdbc connector, extract the **mysql-connector-jar-x.x.x-bin.jar** file.

If you are using intellij simply create a `lib` folder inside of the `WEB-INF` folder.

Once you have added the above you will need to add the jar file to your project. Go to `File > Project Structure` then select `Libraries`. Click on the `+` icon and add the jar file from your lib folder and save. Hope this helps!